# Multisite Redirect for Home Page Only

Tags: multisite, redirect

I am trying to get the home page only (index) of specific blogs in my multisite instance to redirect to  another URL entirely. I want people to be able to resolve links to individual pages/articles, just the home page will redirect.

Not all the sub-sites in multisite,just 1 or 2.

The intent is to basically 'archive' the site, but move the index page to a new URL

How can I specify specific blogs on the stack? Is this better done as a header redirect? Can it be done in htaccess? There doesnt seem to be an individual dir for each sub-site with its respective htaccess, otherwise it would be pretty straightforward. Target the IDs of the blogs?

Something like WP_Maintenance comes close but only redirects once logged in. I cant seem to find a plugin that does this specifically either, but would be happy to make one if it could be hooked in this fashion.

Im familiar with htaccess, but how can I target specific blogs? I have found examples and posts on several issues that are close, but not this exactly. Im sure this is something dreadfully simple that Im overlooking.

Most importantly Im looking for a 'Wordpress safe' answer that won't have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect if you're on the front page of a given site with [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#The_Front_Page). You can use the [`init` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) to do a [`wp_redirect()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) to any absolute URI you want.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse182623_redirect_home_page_only' );
function wpse182623_redirect_home_page_only() {
    if( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://example.com/some-other-page/' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

[Put this into a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and activate that plugin on any sites where you need the front page to redirect elsewhere.

---

### Reference

- [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#The_Front_Page)
- [`init` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init)
- [`wp_redirect()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)
- [Writing a Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)

Comment: for posterity, this doesnt trigger a 'headers already sent' by PHP then? This seems terribly obvious. Thanks for the info.

Comment: From the [`init` docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init): "Fires after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent." So I think it should be fine, but I haven't tested it to be 100% sure.